# How to send iMessage with AppleScript to self and get notification

Tags: python, iphone, applescript, imessage

I set up a script using AppleScript to send a text to myself. When the script runs, it opens iMessage on my computer and thus the message is marked as read. Therefore, the notification does not show up on my phone. Is there a way to send the text without opening up iMessage on my computer so the message is not read?

Comment: As a rule, Messages will only give a notification if the Messages app is in the background or closed entirely, not if the app is in the foreground. If you want it to give you a notification, activate some other app (like the Finder) just before you send your message off, then quit Messages while it's still in the background. It should keep it as 'unread' so that it propagates across devices.

Comment: @TedWrigley Thanks for the suggestion! I tried quitting messages and when I send the message I get the notification on my Mac but not my iPhone. On my Mac it shoes the new message icon and the message preview notification pops up as well. Also, the messages app now has the indicator that it's now running. When I open messages on my Mac, the message shows up as being read at the time it was sent, which is probably why I don't get any notification on my iPhone.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're goal here is. Maybe you want to skip apple scripting messages entirely, and use applescriptobjc to send a message in the background? let me play with it a little bit and see what I can see. P.s.: in the future, please post what code you have; that saves the rest of us from the effort of rewriting it.

Comment: @TedWrigley The AppleScript is called by another script whenever a change in a website occurs. I want to be notified of that change by text